# file_put_contents doesn't create files right away

Tags: php

I have a script that pulls 1 million records and writes them to a multiple files on the disc in chunks of 4000 in each file. From my observation it seems like the files don't get created on the disc until the end of the process when the script is about to be done. Why is that? Can someone explain that process? In my case it is unfortunate since I want to process whatever is memory, save it to a disc and proceed to another file. This way I'm hoping to avoid any memory issues. Here is the script:

```
public function test()
{

    $this->load->model('Marketing_data_model');
    $records = $this->Marketing_data_model->get_messages();
    $n = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($records as $record)
    {

        $msg = '{"index" : {"_index" : "mymessages" , "_type" : "data" , "_id" : "' . $record['message_id'] . '"}} \n' . json_encode($record) . '\n';

        file_put_contents($filename, $msg, FILE_APPEND);

        if ($j >= 4000)
        {
            $filename = 'dump/dump-' .$n. '.txt';   

            $n++;
            $j = 0;
        }
        $j++;

    }

}
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately same issue here:

```
public function test()
    {
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Marketing_data_model');
        $records = $this->Marketing_data_model->get_messages();
        $n = 0;
        $j = 0;
        $msg = '';
        foreach ($records as $record)
        {

            $msg .= '{"index" : {"_index" : "mymessages" , "_type" : "data" , "_id" : "' . $record['message_id'] . '"}} \n' . json_encode($record) . '\n';

            if ($j >= 100)
            {   
                $fp = fopen('dump/dump-' .$n. '.txt', 'w');
                fwrite($fp, $msg);
                fclose($fp);
                $n++;
                $j = 0;
                $msg = '';
            }
            else
            {
                $j++;
            }    


        }

    }
```

Comment: You should try with a file handler. Try with fopen. Then open and close the input stream for smaller chunks. 200 would be a good size compromise.

Comment: Seconda point filename is not assigned before the 4.000th iteration. It is like tuo are writing a large undefined file somewhere for the first 3999 iterations and then youare creating a file for any iteration.

Comment: I added a file handler. Please check. To me it looks like the same issue.

Comment: Perhaps simply some kind of cache-before-write mechanism at work? Be it on behalf of PHP itself, or the OS, or the HDD(/SSD?)

Comment: _“From my observation it seems”_ – please be – a lot – more specific as to how these observations were made, and what exactly they were.

Comment: “From my observation it seems” - meaning that I don't see files being created on the disc until the actual script finishes. Let's say that it takes 10 mins to finish, I won't see any files in the folder until it is actually done, when I would expect it to create them on the fly.